# PHP/Regex replace (table > td) tag by tag (table > tr > td)

Tags: php, regex

I would create an expression or a code that adds the "tr" tag between the table and td, noting that the table has attributes...

```
<table border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td bgcolor=...
<table width="780"><td align=...
```

I would have to stay that way

```
<table border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr><td bgcolor=...
<table width="780"><tr><td align=...
```

There are several combinations of attributes in the table, have to cover all

Can someone help me?

Sorry for the spelling errors, I used Google translator

Comment: And how did you come to the conclusion you'd be able to craft a regex for that? (Given that you have nothing to show yet). -- For this case, a DOM traversal frontend is certainly simpler to use.

Comment: @druzion Can you solve this problem?

Comment: @mario You have an example?

Comment: @mario `$re = "/(<table.*>)(?<!<tr>)(<td.*)/";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe

```
$re = "/(<table.*>)(<td.*)/"; 
$str = "<table border=\"0\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><td bgcolor=...\n<table width=\"780\"><td align=..."; 
$subst = "$1<tr>$2"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

here is the demo... https://regex101.com/r/oO9hX0/1

Comment: `<table.*?>` is correct, if you are matching greedy you will match everything from the first `<table` to the last `<td`.

Comment: And if the table already has the tag tr?

Comment: I forgot to put this observation, some already have the tag tr ... it is possible?

Comment: `$re = "/(<table.*>)(?<!<tr>)(<td.*)/";` ;)